# Accessibility to variable of superclass when initializing the subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to access a variable of a superclass from its subclass when initializing the subclass.
I can't understand why direct access to a variable of its superclass is not possible, but accessing it via the getter function of the parent is possible. (it is a public variable)

```
class Parent(object):
    def __init__(self, age=22):
        self.age = age

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
      #  self.age = super().age - 15  # This line causes error
        self.age = super().get_age() - 15 # The line works


def main():
    c = Child()
    print("The child's age is " + str(c.get_age()))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: You just need `self.age` or `self.get_age()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`super()` function returns a proxy object representing the superclass which gives access to methods of the superclass by searching for the method. However it doesn't give access to variables in the parent class. It's just how `super()` works. To access the variables of superclass here, you can simply use `self.age`. For more information on how `super()` works, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super).